# Smooth discrete 2D coordinates

Tags: python, math

I'm searching for a way to smooth coordinates. 
For example, given the coordinates

```
co = [(1,10), (2,10), (3,9), (3,8), (3,7), (2,6), ...]
```

I would like smooth them like this:

[image]

What algorithm or library should I use?

Is this possibly related [Smooth a trajectory with splrep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513244/smooth-a-trajectory-with-splrep)?

Answer (score 1):

[Douglas-Peucker algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) is intended to simplify polylines. I think there are some Python implementations. [One example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573997/reduce-number-of-points-in-line#)

Comment: I wrote an answer with a little animation of the Douglas-Peucker algorithm if you are interested... http://stackoverflow.com/a/36937976/2836621